# React Native: Change the default language used in permission requests and alerts

Tags: react-native

I am developing an app in React Native and want to change the default language across the whole app. More specifically, I want to localize the language used in system-generated alerts, e.g. permission request for push notification, permission request for camera roll access, etc.

Existing libararies, e.g., [react-native-localize](https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-localize), let me localize the texts in components, but I do not think there is a way to set up the default language to display the system-generated alerts in those libraries.

Is there a way to do this in react native?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Which library you are using for translations?

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito, I am using react-native-localize.